# Django adding to database with foreign key while still showing the informations from the other model

Tags: python, django, database, model, foreign-keys

I want to add elements to my database (for model Student) while having stuff from another model (School) be displayed alongside the form for the Student.\

This is the models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('basiccbv:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators= [validators.MinValueValidator(1),validators.MaxValueValidator(20)],default=1)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='students')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

In my views.py I have this:

```
class SchoolDetailedView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basiccbv/school_detail.html'
    # What i want is when I visit the link in the description I want to
    # to see the school stuff and the form to add the student in this new 
    # view

class StudentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.School
    # I tried using the Student but that I don't know how to display the 
    # school information, I tried with related_name = 'students' but it 
    # didn't work(I don't know if that can be done the way that intended it 
    # or I just don't have the knowledge )  
    fields = ['name', 'age']
    # If I use School I could get the name of the school in the title and 
    # its primary key, but than I don't know how to display the form and 
    # vise versa 
    template_name = 'basiccbv/student_update.html'
```

This is the .html file that gets me to the page where I need the form.
The link is the one calling 'basiccbv:studentupdate'
The related_name students was used here but I still can't figure out if it can 
be done for adding stuff the way I want

```
<h1>Welcome to the school details page</h1>
<h2>School details:</h2>
<p>Name: {{ school_detail.name }}</p>
<p>Principal: {{ school_detail.principal }}</p>
<p>Location: {{ school_detail.location }}</p>
<h3>Students:</h3>
{% for student in school_detail.students.all %}
<p>{{ student.name }} who is {{ student.age }} years old.</p>
{% endfor %}
<div class="container">
<p><a href="{% url 'basiccbv:studentupdate' pk=school_detail.pk %}">Add a 
student</a></p>
```

And here is the .html file with the form

```
              ## I changed this part bellow but nothing worked
<h1>Student coming to {{ student.school.name }}</h1>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add student">
</form>
```

I'm really stuck and can't find any information about this but if you can help me or give any advice thank you.

The way I used to add students was with admin and for schools I used admin until I created the view for creating Schools which worked with no problems(probably because there were no foreign keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take this approach

Forms:

```
# We need to define a new form first
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Student
         fields = ['name', 'age']
```

Views:

```
# we are using form view for using the form mentioned above
class StudentCreateView(FormView):
     form_class = StudentForm
     success_url = "/"

     def get(self, request, school_id, **kwargs):
         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)  # getting context, ie: the form
         context[school] = School.objects.get(pk=school_id)  # updating the context with school object using the PK provided with the url
         return self.render_to_response(context)

     def post(self, request, school_id, **kwargs):
        # overriding default implementation
        form = self.get_form()  
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, school_id)  # passing the pk value to form valid function to override
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, school_id):
        # overriding default implementation
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.school = School.objects.get(id=school_id)  # saving the school information to the object
        self.object.save()
        return super(StudentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Template

```
# template
    <h1>Student coming to {{ school.name }}</h1>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add student">
    </form>
```

Urls

```
path('school/student-update/<int:school_id>/', StudentCreateView.as_view(), name='studentupdate'),
```